# echo form data?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to produce a registration form, basically i have 4 pages, page one asks for first name, last name and email, page two asks for date of birth and password, page 3 will ask some statistics/checkbox items and page 4 will submit the form.

At the moment i'm trying to echo the data from one form on one page over to page 2, 3 and then finally all submit together in page4 into the mysql database.

I'm receiving an error updating the database message.

Can someone tell me if im doing it right or if theres an easier way to do it?

Thanks;

```
<form class="" method="post" action="register_p2.php">
<div class="row first_name">
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
</div>

<div class="row last_name">
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
</div>

<div class="row email">
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"  />
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Next >"  />

</form>
```

PART 2 / PAGE 2

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
<?php
// GET ACCOUNT INFORMATION FROM FORM AND ASSIGN VARIABLES
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
?>
<?php
/*
// ECHO ACCOUNT INFORMATION
echo "<strong> Account Information: </strong>";
echo "<br />";
echo First Name: ";
echo "<br />";
echo $first_name;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "Last Name: ";
echo "<br />";
echo $last_name;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "Email: ";
echo "<br />";
echo $email;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
*/
?>

<?php
////// SEND TO DATABASE


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Database Constants
define("DB_SERVER", "#######");
define("DB_USER", "######");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "######");

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// 2. Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$query="INSERT INTO registrations (Id,
first_name,
last_name,
email

 )
VALUES('NULL',
'".$first_name."',
'".$last_name."',
'".$email."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
?>
<?php
function confirm_query($result_set) {
                if (!$result_set) {
                    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                }
        }
function get_user_id() {
    global $connection;
    global $email;
    $query = "SELECT *
                FROM registrations
                WHERE email = \"$email\"
                ";
        $user_id_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($user_id_set);
        return $user_id_set;
        }
?>
<?php
$user_id_set = get_user_id();
while ($user_id = mysql_fetch_array($user_id_set)) {
    $cookie1 = "{$user_id["id"]}";
    setcookie("registrations", $cookie1, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

}
?>


    <? ob_flush(); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Register</title>

            <!-- The stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />

            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="main">

            <h2>Step 2: Security Details</h2>
            <br/>

                <form class="" method="post" action="register_p3.php">

                    <div class="row date_of_birth">
                        <input type="text" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="D.O.B 10/02/1990" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="row password">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="row password2">
                        <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password (Confirm)"  />
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Next >"  />

                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- JavaScript includes - jQuery, the complexify plugin and our own script.js -->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.complexify.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>     
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what error u are getting ?

Comment: Try to avoid using `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated now, and bring serious security implications with them. Much better is to look into the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

try this using session ,

```
    <? ob_start(); 
         session_start();?>
<?php
// GET ACCOUNT INFORMATION FROM FORM AND ASSIGN VARIABLES
$first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
?>
<?php
/*
// ECHO ACCOUNT INFORMATION
echo "<strong> Account Information: </strong>";
echo "<br />";
echo First Name: ";
echo "<br />";
echo $first_name;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "Last Name: ";
echo "<br />";
echo $last_name;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "Email: ";
echo "<br />";
echo $email;
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
*/
?>

<?php
////// SEND TO DATABASE


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Database Constants
define("DB_SERVER", "#######");
define("DB_USER", "######");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "######");

// 1. Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// 2. Select a database to use
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$query="INSERT INTO registrations (Id,
first_name,
last_name,
email

 )
VALUES('NULL',
'".$first_name."',
'".$last_name."',
'".$email."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
?>
<?php
function confirm_query($result_set) {
                if (!$result_set) {
                    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
                }
        }
function get_user_id() {
    global $connection;
    global $email;
    $query = "SELECT *
                FROM registrations
                WHERE email = \"$email\"
                ";
        $user_id_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($user_id_set);
        return $user_id_set;
        }
?>
<?php
$user_id_set = get_user_id();
while ($user_id = mysql_fetch_array($user_id_set)) {
    $cookie1 = "{$user_id["id"]}";
    setcookie("registrations", $cookie1, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */

}
?>


    <? ob_flush(); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Register</title>

            <!-- The stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />

            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="main">

            <h2>Step 2: Security Details</h2>
            <br/>

                <form class="" method="post" action="register_p3.php">

                    <div class="row date_of_birth">
                        <input type="text" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="D.O.B 10/02/1990" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="row password">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="row password2">
                        <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Password (Confirm)"  />
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Next >"  />

                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- JavaScript includes - jQuery, the complexify plugin and our own script.js -->
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.complexify.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>     
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want information to be available on more than one page you should store it in a session. Just do something like this when you store the $_POST values into variables, and be sure to put a session_start(); call at the top of your page.

```
<?php
session_start();
// other php code here

$_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
?>
```

Then you could access them on any page by calling $_SESSION['first_name'] or whatever variable you want to access. Just be sure to include session_start(); at the top of every page that requires using these variables.

Comment: ok thanks when i start a session do i need to include a database connection on every page or only on the last page?

Comment: @JamesMatthews Sessions don't require a database, so only on the last page (if that's the only place you interact with the database).

Comment: ok good and then when i come to the last page and need to call all the session data how would i go about inserting that into the database?

Comment: If you find any of these answers helpful you really should up-vote them and accept one of them. People are much more likely to help you in the future if you give them good reputation for helping you.